# How to track what pages your users are visiting while logged in

Tags: iframe, coldfusion, air

I would like to track my students as they work on their assignments, but in a good way.  I want to see their search strategies, and how long it took them to complete the assignment.

I'm envisioning a sort of fast-forward system, where I can playback what they did, skipping the long delays like when they go to eat.  I could also see the students using this in reverse, watching how long it took me to grade their paper.

So, is it possible, maybe with an iframe, to track each url that they visit?

I'd also have to not allow pasting from the clipboard into the answer box unless the clipboard contents come from the iframe.

So they're free to use any search engine - I just need to see how they got their answer.

I might have to use AIR, I don't know.

File this under ColdFusion because I'm a ColdFusion developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the student leaves your domain, cross-domain security prevents you from accessing the DOM properties of the iFrame. You could accomplish what you want to do by proxying all of their searches using cfhttp and logging what they search from there.  You would then need to make all of the search returned links into same-domain, proxy queries again to log which results they click.  Do-able, but probably not as simple and flexible as you were thinking.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to know any of this *with certainty* unless you control the whole browser experience. You can track what they do on your site - but not where they go elsewhere. Sharindo's answer is therefore the appropriate one (proxy their requests using cfhttp) albeit an expensive one. It won't prevent them from simply opening a new browser window however.

With regard to cut and paste restrictions. You can can turn off cut and paste with some JS and then provide a button that can "paste" whatever the student has selected on the page into the appropriate text box. So... a student can search (using your chttp proxy page you created), select information and then click the button to paste it to the answer box. You can't turn off cut and paste "selectively" that I know of (as in, if they copy certain content disallow it but allow it for certain other content).

Tracking is somewhat easier and can be straightforward... again, you can only track traffic that you control. You can Create a simple audit/log function to a table or a file and then use the data to create reports showing paths through the site. But you can't track where *else* they have been - at least not without installing a proxy on the computer itself - and that might be (will be) considered underhanded I think (ha).

So... there are ways to meet your basic requirements if you stick to just your site, but none of them are without flaws and perhaps none of them give you exactly what you want.

I would add (regarding cut and paste and your proxy). That even semi-clever tech savvy students can install something like firebug and circumvent your careful rules. It's a bit of a losing battle I'm afraid :)

Comment: Mark, thanks for such a thoughtful response.  I've found 4 or 5 techniques to prevent copy/paste, so I'm pretty comfortable disabling that.  If students are that tech savvy, then they will go through more work defeating the system than doing the work.  After all - I'm teaching them how to find information :)

Comment: Maybe I can have them copy/paste their answer and in a separate input field paste the url where they found it.   That's a compromise, but if I can't track their usage, that might be a 2nd or 3rd best.

Comment: Yes... if you make it a requirement then they have to source their info. I like it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a date time stamp to a database table, and the url they are on as well...  I use to track searches on my site by doing this... And just passing the variables u need... So ie: at 8am - Student Bob Logged in... 8:01 went to assignment page... Searched for this or that...  For tracking the page... u can use some of these...

```
 #CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT# - tracks O/S they are on... Can see ipad, iphone, android, msie
 #cgi.http_referer# - track where they came from
 #cgi.PATH_INFO# or #URL.path# - get url their on...
```

Just some different things to try... And then dump stuff into a database table etc...

Comment: Merle: What technique do you use to track that they go to Google?

Comment: Ahh... Not sure.. this I assume is why u want to track them in an iFrame... Haven't really done that... Lose them I guess once they are off site and out of iFrame...

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Your web server will be logging everything and if not you can turn it on, then you can use a log analysis tool to delve through the logs.

And if that doesn't give you what you want, you can write something to pass the logs.

Comment: Thanks Dale!  Everything's got to be associated with their grade.  So I can't just use off-the-shelf software.  It's got to be integrated into their final grade.